# Kafka JsonSchema Producer Issues with incompatible Schema

Tags: apache-kafka, groovy, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to produce to a Kafka topic which has a JsonSchema set for validation, this is done in Groovy script and I have the equivalent class with all the fields that are present in the schema.

This is the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/myEvent/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "Event": {
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field4": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field5": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field6": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field7": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field8": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "field1",
        "field2"
      ],
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "Event": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Event"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Groovy code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.annotations.Schema

public class Event {
@JsonProperty("field1")
public String field1;
@JsonProperty("field2")
public String field2;
@JsonProperty("field3")
public String field3;
@JsonProperty("field4")
public String field4;
@JsonProperty("field5")
public String field5;
@JsonProperty("field6")
public String field6;
@JsonProperty("field7")
public String field7;
@JsonProperty("field8")
public String field8;

public Event(String field1,String field2,String field3,String field4,String field5,String field6,String field7,String field8){
    this.field1 = field1
    this.field2 = field2
    this.field3 = field3
    this.field4 = field4
    this.field5 = field5
    this.field6 = field6
    this.field7 = field7
    this.field8 = field8
}
}


public class MyRecord {

@JsonProperty("Event")
public Event event;
public MyRecord(Event event){
    this.event=event
}

}
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "http://localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
props.put("auto.register.schemas", "false");
props.put("json.oneof.for.nullables", "false");

Producer<String, MyRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, MyRecord>(props);

String topic = "test";
String key = "testkey";
MyRecord user = new MyRecord(new Event("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"));

ProducerRecord<String, MyRecord> record
      = new ProducerRecord<String, MyRecord>(topic, key, user);
producer.send(record).get();
producer.close();
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving JSON schema: {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "My Record",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "Event": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Event"
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "Event": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field3": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field4": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field5": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field6": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field7": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field8": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And basically if I copy-paste the schema from the error and set it on the topic the producer works. The this is that I don't want to modify the original schema. Also another point is that I can publish to the topic with Postman with the content-type 'application/vnd.kafka.jsonschema.v2+json' and this body

```
    "value_schema_id": 5,
    "records": [
        {
            "value": {
                "Event": {
                    "field1": "1",
                    "field2": "2",
                    "field3": "3",
                    "field4": "4",
                    "field5": "5",
                    "field6": "6",
                    "field7": "7",
                    "field8": "8"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but Kafka is not HTTP service. Remove the protocol prefix from bootstrap servers

Comment: You have `auto.register.schemas=false`, why? That may explain why it cannot retrieve it

Comment: by default auto.register.schemas is set to true, which then modifies the schema on the topic when the message gets published. And because I don't want the schema to be changed, i'm setting it to false.

Comment: Try producing with it enabled to a brand new topic. Then compare the schemas to find the difference